# difference between ons-toolbar and ons-tabbar-item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

What are the different between `ons-tabbar-item` and `ons-tabbar-item` ?? I read through documentation and both are similar at a glance, could you tell me situation of each should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe tabbar is the tab panel at the bottom and toolbar is the panel on the top but it could be on the bottom by using bottom-toolbar component.

Use tabbar in your app if you want to have multiple featured pages because each tabbar item loads url to a page.

Toolbar is more like header bar in your app with navigation tools and other tools and there's no ons-toolbar-item.